# Does the product functor preserve quotient maps?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, category-theory

In Hatcher's *Algebraic Topology*, he presents a [proof](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e7aGc.png) that if $(X,A)$ satisfies the homotopy extension property, and $A$ is contractible, then $X \simeq X/A$.

Part of Hatcher's proof goes: Suppose that $q: X \to X/A$ is the quotient map. Taking a homotopy $f : X \times I \to X$ such that $f_t(A) \subseteq A$ for all $t$, he then reasons that $q \circ f: X \times A \to X /A$ descends to a homotopy $X /A \times I \to X/A$. It's clear to me how to define such a map for each $t$. I asked myself why a map defined that way for each $t$ should then be continuous on $X /A \times I$, and I wasn't sure. One way that we could guarantee it was continuous is if $q \times 1_I: X \times I \to X/A \times I$ had the [characteristic property](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotient_space_%28topology%29#Properties) of the quotient. But I'm not sure whether this is the case.

My questions are

1. Is he reasoning that if $\varphi: S \to \overline{S}$ is a quotient map, then
   $\varphi \times 1_T: S \times T \to \overline{S} \times T$ is a quotient map
   for any topological space $T$? [**Edit:** this is not true.]
2. What is going on here categorically?
       I haven't before seen a situation where starting with a product $S \times T$, we then obtain $\overline{S} \times T$, where $\overline{S}$ is a quotient of $S$ (however we may define a quotient categorically).

With regard to 1, I tried to prove this more general proposition, but ran into some problems. Taking $U \subseteq S \times T$ to be an open saturated set, I wanted to show that $(\varphi \times 1_T)(U)$ was open. Letting $x \in U$ I take a basic neighborhood of $x$ of the form $\mathcal{O}_S \times \mathcal{O}_T$, and I would like to show that it has open image $\varphi (\mathcal{O}_S) \times \mathcal{O}_T$. I can say that $\varphi (\mathcal{O}_S)$ is open if I know that $\mathcal{O}_S$ is saturated, but I'm not sure why I can assume this.

**Edit:** I see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/31697/when-is-the-product-of-two-quotient-maps-a-quotient-map) that since $I$ is locally compact Hausdorff, we have the result we want about the quotient, but the result is not true in general. I still wonder about the categorical part. Also, I wonder if what I'm saying is implicit in his presentation, or I am missing something easier.

Comment: This http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/833042/certain-colimit-and-product-in-category-of-topological-spaces/833227#833227 is related, and talks a little about the categorical part ($-\times Y$ having an adjoint)

Comment: I'll explain how to complete the proof you started: If $x=(a,t)\in U$, the goal is to find an open product $W\times V\subseteq U$ such that $W$ is saturated, as that would imply $(\varphi\times 1_T)(W\times V)=\varphi(W)\times V$ is an open neighborhood of $(\varphi(a),t)$ contained in $(\varphi\times 1)(U)$. So take a compact neighborhood $K$ of $t$ such that $\{a\}\times K\subseteq U$, and let $W$ be the largest set such that $W\times K\subseteq U$. It is easy to show that $W$ is non-empty open and saturated. Then $W\times\mathring K$ is the desired open product.

Comment: The situation you wonder about in 2 is very common in cartesian closed categories, where every product functor is a left adjoint, at least if we let "quotient" mean "regular epimorphism", as it does here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'll explain how to complete the proof you started: If $x=(a,t)∈U$, the goal is to find an open product $W×V⊆U$ such that $W$ is saturated, as that would imply $(φ×1_T)(W×V)=φ(W)×V$ is an open neighborhood of $(φ(a),t)$ contained in $(φ×1)(U)$. So take a compact neighborhood $K$ of $t$ such that $\{a\}×K⊆U$, and let $W$ be the largest set such that $W×K⊆U$. It is easy to show that $W$ is non-empty open and saturated. Then $W×\mathring K$ is the desired open product.

Hatcher uses the fact that the product $q\times 1_I$ is a quotient map several times in his book, but as far as I remember, he never points out that the local compactness of the unit interval is essential. The only mentioning of local compactness in this context which I see is in the appendix in proposition A.17.
The proof there is categorical. It makes use of the adjunctions $\mathbf{Top}(X×Y,Z)\cong \mathbf{Top}(X,[Y,Z])$ and 
$\mathbf{Set}(X×Y,Z)\cong \mathbf{Set}(X,Z^Y)$, where $[Y,Z]$ is the space of maps (by *map* I mean continuous function) $Y\to Z$, equipped with the compact-open topology, while $Z^Y$ is the set of all functions between mere sets. The adjunction in $\mathbf{Top}$ is only valid if $Y$ is locally compact.
Assume that $f:Z×Y\to W$ is a function such that $f(q×1)$ is a map. It has an adjunct $f^\flat:Z\to W^Y$ such that $f^\flat q:X\to W^Y$ is the adjunct of $f(q×1)$. On the other hand, the adjunct map $X\to[Y,W]$ of $f(q×1)$ composes with the inclusion function $[Y,W]\hookrightarrow W^Y$ to $f^\flat q$, which by surjectivity of $q$ means that $f^\flat$ is actually a function with codomain $[Y,W]$, and $f^\flat q$ is a map. Since $q$ is a quotient map, we conclude that $f^\flat$ is a map. This implies that its adjunct $f$ is a map as well.

**Edit:** Kevin Carlson reminded me that the quotient maps are precisely the regular epimorphisms in $\mathbf{Top}$, and that this leads to a more elegant proof. Namely, if $R\subseteq X\times X$ is the equivalence relation defining the quotient map $q$, then $R\rightrightarrows X\stackrel q\to Z$ is a coequalizer diagram, where the parallel arrows are the projections. Since $-\times Y$ is a left adjoint functor for locally compact $Y$, it preserves colimits, thus we have a coequalizer diagram $R\times Y\rightrightarrows X\times Y\to Z\times Y$, implying that $q\times 1_Y$ is a quotient map.

Comment: The second paragraph seems more complicated than necessary. Locally compact spaces are exponentiable, so the corresponding product functor is a left adjoint, and thus preserves colimits, such as quotients.

Comment: Every quotient map $q:X\to Z$ is the coequalizer of $R\rightrightarrows X$, where $R$ is the equivalence relation and the maps are the coordinate maps. Applying $-×Y$ gives the coequalizer $R×\Delta_Y\rightrightarrows X×Y\to Z×Y$ of the projections from the product relation in $X\times Y$ since the functor preserves coequalizers. Thanks @KevinCarlson for reminding me :-)

Comment: @EricAuld: See my comment above for an easier argument which Kevin pointed out.